# How to copy data from 1 dataframe into another based on several conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

In my `df1` (including `df1$id`, `df1$datetime_interval`, `df1$datetime_event` and `df1$event`) i'd like to put data from `df2` (including `df2$id`, `df2$datetime_event`) based onder these conditions:

**if** `df1$id` and `df2$id` match

**and** if `df2$datetime_event` is within the `df1$datetime_interval`,

**than** I want the data of `df2$datetime_event` copied in the column of `df1$datetime_event`, of that perticular row in `df1`, **and** a string (for instance "yes") in `df1$event`.

if the conditions aren't met, I want no results (NA)

So:

```
df1
ID        datetime_interval                                  datetime_event    event
1       2019-04-19 21:50:00 UTC--2019-04-20 21:31:00 UTC           NA            NA
1       2019-07-02 04:23:00 UTC--2019-07-02 08:51:00 UTC           NA            NA
2       2019-07-04 19:45:00 UTC--2019-07-05 00:30:00 UTC           NA            NA
3       2019-06-07 08:55:00 UTC--2019-06-07 14:43:00 UTC           NA            NA
3       2019-05-06 17:18:00 UTC--2019-05-06 23:18:00 UTC           NA            NA
6       2019-08-02 22:00:00 UTC--2019-08-04 03:10:00 UTC           NA            NA
```

```
df2
ID        datetime_event                                  
1       2019-04-19 21:55:00        
3       2019-05-06 21:23:00 
5       2019-07-04 19:45:00 
6       2019-05-06 17:18:00
6       2019-08-03 10:10:00
```

I have tried some things but it didn't work out like i want it too. I'm still missing some steps and i don't know how to move on from this. This is what i have so far:

```
for(i in seq_along(df1$id)){
  for(j in seq_along(df2$id)){
    ifelse(df2$id[j] ==  df1$id[i]) {
       ifelse(df2$datetime_event[j] %within% df1$datetime_interval[i] == TRUE){
        df1$datetime_event <- df2$datetime_ic_corr[j]
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

my desired outcome is this:

```
df1
ID        datetime_event                                      datetime_event          event
1       2019-04-19 21:50:00 UTC--2019-04-20 21:31:00 UTC    2019-04-19 21:55:00       yes
1       2019-07-02 04:23:00 UTC--2019-07-02 08:51:00 UTC           NA                  NA
2       2019-07-04 19:45:00 UTC--2019-07-05 00:30:00 UTC           NA                  NA
3       2019-06-07 08:55:00 UTC--2019-06-07 14:43:00 UTC           NA                  NA
3       2019-05-06 17:18:00 UTC--2019-05-06 23:18:00 UTC    2019-05-06 21:23:00        yes
6       2019-08-02 22:00:00 UTC--2019-08-04 03:10:00 UTC    2019-08-03 10:10:00        yes
```

Thank you in advance for all new input! Cause I'm stuck...

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 6), datetime_interval = c("2019-04-19 21:50:00 UTC--2019-04-20 21:31:00 UTC", 
"2019-07-02 04:23:00 UTC--2019-07-02 08:51:00 UTC", "2019-07-04 19:45:00 UTC--2019-07-05 00:30:00 UTC", 
"2019-06-07 08:55:00 UTC--2019-06-07 14:43:00 UTC", "2019-05-06 17:18:00 UTC--2019-05-06 23:18:00 UTC", 
"2019-08-02 22:00:00 UTC--2019-08-04 03:10:00 UTC"), datetime_event = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), event = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

dput(df2)
structure(list(ID = c(1, 3, 5, 6, 6), datetime_event = c("2019-04-19 21:55:00 UTC", 
"2019-05-06 21:23:00 UTC", "2019-07-04 19:45:00 UTC", "2019-05-06 17:18:00 UTC", 
"2019-08-03 10:10:00 UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you share the inputs `df1` and `df2` with `dput`? That will make them copy/pasteable and make it a lot easier for people to demonstrate solutions. Put the output from `dput(df1)` (or perhaps `dput(head(df1))`, if your actual data is bigger than what you show) into your question.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks! I've put them into my question!

Answer (score 0):

Tricky problem. I think this works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# convert datetime_interval to datetime class start and end columns
# and add row IDs
df1 = df1 %>% 
  separate(datetime_interval, into = c("start", "end"), sep = "--") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(start, end), as.POSIXct) %>%
  select(-datetime_event, -event) %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number())

# convert datetime event to datetime class
df2 = df2 %>%
  mutate(datetime_event = as.POSIXct(datetime_event))

# join and filter
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = "ID") %>%
  mutate(
    datetime_event = ifelse(datetime_event >= start & datetime_event <= end, datetime_event, NA),
    event = ifelse(is.na(datetime_event), NA, "yes")
  ) %>%
  arrange(row_id, datetime_event) %>%
  group_by(row_id) %>%
  slice(1)
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
# # Groups:   row_id [6]
#      ID start               end                 row_id datetime_event event
#   <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>               <int>          <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 2019-04-19 21:50:00 2019-04-20 21:31:00      1     1555725300 yes  
# 2     1 2019-07-02 04:23:00 2019-07-02 08:51:00      2             NA NA   
# 3     2 2019-07-04 19:45:00 2019-07-05 00:30:00      3             NA NA   
# 4     3 2019-06-07 08:55:00 2019-06-07 14:43:00      4             NA NA   
# 5     3 2019-05-06 17:18:00 2019-05-06 23:18:00      5     1557192180 yes  
# 6     6 2019-08-02 22:00:00 2019-08-04 03:10:00      6     1564841400 yes
```